# Django and React Setup

Tags: javascript, date, ecmascript-6

I am looking for a solid guide to provide detail on how to set up React within a Django project. I have gone by the [django-webpack-loader](https://github.com/ezhome/django-webpack-loader) read me file, as well as a site it references located [here](http://owaislone.org/blog/webpack-plus-reactjs-and-django/). Both are very easy to follow but I run into issues around the webpack.config.js file. I either get compile errors or nothing renders.

Here is the webpack.config.js file from link 1

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: './assets/js/index',
  output: {
      path: path.resolve('./assets/webpack_bundles/'),
      filename: "[name]-[hash].js"
  },

  plugins: [
    new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'})
  ]
}
```

Here is the produced error

```
ERROR in ./assets/js/index.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:13)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| var App = require('./app')
| 
| React.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('react-app'))
```

Here is the webpack.config.js file from link 2

```
var path = require("path")
var webpack = require('webpack')
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker')

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,

  entry: './assets/js/index', // entry point of our app. assets/js/index.js should require other js modules and dependencies it needs

  output: {
      path: path.resolve('./assets/bundles/'),
      filename: "[name]-[hash].js",
  },

  plugins: [
    new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'}),
  ],

  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader'}, // to transform JSX into JS
    ],
  },

  resolve: {
    modules: ['node_modules', 'bower_components'],
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
}
```

This does not produce an error, and the appropriate javascript bunfle file is shown in the django template in a script tag, but nothing renders.

My strong suit is Python, not JS, so I am having issues diagnosing the problems. The setup is done correctly in settings.py and I do have a webpack-stats.json, but something is off with the actual javascript parts. I've installed the following with npm.

```
    ○ react
    ○ webpack
    ○ webpack-bundle-tracker
    ○ babel
    ○ babel-loader
    ○ babel-core
    ○ babel-eslint
    ○ babel-preset-es2015
    ○ babel-preset-react
    ○ babel-preset-stage-0
    ○ babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy
    ○ eslint
```

this is my assets/js/index.js file

```
var React = require('react')

var App = React.createClass({
   render: function(){
       return <h1>Hello, world.</h1>
   }
})

React.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('react-app'))
```

this is the django template

```
{% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="react-app"></div>
    {% render_bundle 'main' %}
  </body>
</html>
```

beyond that, the settings.py file, my views.py and urls.py are all correct when following the django-webpack-loader guide.

Comment: can you show your template.

Comment: try renaming the index.js to index.jsx

Comment: updating my question

Comment: I followed this guide instead and it worked - https://github.com/mbrochh/django-reactjs-boilerplate